# watermark png image with its created date

Tags: bash, date, png, exif

I need to watermark my png images with its created date.

I am trying to read `png` files `exif data`. But Captured `png` file with `screenshot` tool on linux doesn't have exif data.

I am using below script to watermark my png images with its created date :

```
#!/bin/bash

echo "Script for addding time stamp"
date --iso-8601=seconds  
shopt -s extglob

find . -iname "*.jpg" -o -iname "*.jpeg" -o -iname "*.tif" -o \
 -iname "*.tiff" -o -iname "*.png" | 

## Go through the results, saving each as $img
while IFS= read -r img; do
    ## Find will return full paths, so an image in the current
    ## directory will be ./foo.jpg and the first dot screws up 
    ## bash's pattern matching. Use basename and dirname to extract
    ## the needed information.
    name=$(basename "$img")
    path=$(dirname "$img")
    ext="${name/#*./}";
    
    ## Check whether this file has exif data
    if exiv2 "$img" 2>&1 | grep timestamp >/dev/null 
    ## If it does, read it and add the water mark   
    then
    echo "Processing $img...";
    convert "$img" -gravity SouthEast  -pointsize 22 -fill black \
             -annotate +30+30  %[exif:DateTimeOriginal] \
             "$path"/"${name/%.*/.time.$ext}";
    ## If the image has no exif data, use the creation date of the file.
    else
    echo "No Exif data in $img...";
      date=$(stat "$img" | grep Modify | cut -d ' ' -f 2,3 | cut -d ':' -f1,2)
      convert "$img" -gravity SouthEast  -pointsize 22 -fill black \
             -annotate +30+30  "$date" \
             "$path"/"${name/%.*/.time.$ext}";
    fi 
done
```

**Expected Watermark format output:**

But I need watermark with below date format (like its output `$ date --iso-8601=seconds`) -

```
2021-11-29T07:46:15+01:00
```

**Actual WaterMark format output:**
But png image `stat` doesn't have this format so my watermark comes as -

```
2021-11-29 07:27
```

Can any one suggest me how can I modify my script to get the expected watermark on my png image.

OR

Is there any another best way to watermark png images with its date created.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

On Linux, you can get the date format you want like this:

```
date=$(date -d "@$(stat -c %Y "$img")" --iso-8601=seconds)
```

- `stat -c %Y` to use format specifiers for `stat` output
- `%Y` is the date of last modification, in epoch seconds
- GNU `date -d @<epoch-seconds>` to specify an *input* date, `@` specifies epoch seconds format
- Then specify the output format (`--iso-8601=seconds`)
- BSD/Mac has slightly different syntax for `stat`

Comment: It worked as per the expected output.

Answer (score 1):

Please try this on a COPY of a few images in a spare directory as I have not tested it. I think `exiftool` will add file modification date to your images in place of EXIF DateTimeOriginal:

```
exiftool -v "-FileModifyDate>DateTimeOriginal" *.png
```

You can see a summary of all time-related data about an image like this:

```
exiftool -time:all -G1 -a -s SOMEIMAGE.PNG
[System]        FileModifyDate                  : 2021:11:23 09:48:30+00:00
[System]        FileAccessDate                  : 2021:11:27 13:38:21+00:00
[System]        FileInodeChangeDate             : 2021:11:26 23:41:21+00:00
```

If you add the `exiftool` tag to your question, one of the specialists will probably suggest how you can change it to only add the data if not already present.

---

Also, consider using **GNU Parallel** if you have lots of images. Just put `[gnu-parallel]` in the Search box, along with `image`.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to tweak the output of the `stat` command on the image file,
would you please try:

```
datestr=$(date --iso-8601=seconds -d @$(stat --printf='%Z\n' "$img"))
```

It assumes your `date` command supports `-d` option.
BTW I've changed the variable name to `datestr` to avoid the namespace
conflict although it is harmless and just confusing.

Comment: Thanks for your answer too. I have tried your answer as well. It also worked well.But I have considered the similar answer posted as answer from @dan.

Comment: Okay. It doesn't matter. (Although I've beaten him in a couple of minutes :)